# How to encode a swift string into an integer

Tags: arrays, swift, encoding

Let's say that I had a string n (in the swift programming language) that consists of various characters, such as "uFxXobTXkaaU57yrm3hF". I want to encode this into an integer that I can easily decode to get back to my original string. I'm not sure how to do this - I believe there may be some function for this, but I don't know what it is. Does anyone know a function that can do this? (Both the encoding and decoding).

Comment: Swift integers are 64-bit binary numbers, these *cannot* encode arbitrary strings (there are infinitely many different strings, but only finitely many 64-bit numbers). Or are you thinking of “big integers”? – It may help if you explain what you are trying to achieve with that encoding/decoding.

Comment: In general, what you want isn't possible. But it might be possible in a limited and specific case. As already mentioned, please update your question with more specific details about what you are really trying to do.

Comment: Its pretty simple. I have a string "uFxXobTXkaaU57yrm3hF" and want to convert that to some integer, which i can convert back to the string "uFxXobTXkaaU57yrm3hF".

Comment: No, that's not "pretty simple." That string is 20 characters long. Assuming a simple 8-bit ASCII string (and that's not a good assumption) that's 160 bits of data. Longer strings would take more bits to represent. Integers in Swift are 64 bits. They can represent at most 8 ASCII characters worth of information. I guess you could convert each character in your string into a 3 digit number (with leading zeros) representing its value in ASCII, and then just combine the digits into a huge numeric value, but WHY? What would you do with such a huge numeric value? It would not be easy to decode back.

Comment: What do you expect to do with this conversion? Is your string ASCII? What about characters like ü, π, ∂, ß, and other unicode characters? Your premise that there is some simple way to convert an arbitrary-length string to an integer is wrong, full stop.

Comment: @wis-fellow There's a reason why people are asking for more details. Sure, if you only have that one string and will only ever have that one string then it's trivial to encode the string to a number and decode it back to the original. But it's unlikely you only have a single string. Without knowing what problem you are really trying to solve, no one can give you an appropriate solution. If you wish to get a good answer, please take the time to provide more details in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to convert a string of any length with any characters into an Int, because an Int only has 64 bits.

However, if you constrain the problem, then you could convert strings up to a certain length that contain only certain characters into an Int. Or better still, into an unsigned 64-bit Int.

For example, you could restrict the supported characters to the following:

`0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`

There are 62 characters in this set, so each character would require a minimum of 6 bits to be represented as an integer. It would therefore be possible to represent a string containing up to 10 of these characters as an unsigned 64-bit integer.

Here is a Playground example with a couple of functions that do the conversion. This code is lacking a length check on the strings, but you could add that.

```swift
let bitsPerChar = 6
let charMask = UInt64(63)
let alphabet = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
let alphabetArray = Array(alphabet)

func string2number(_ s: String) -> UInt64 {
    var result = UInt64.zero
    for char in s {
        result <<= bitsPerChar
        let pos: Int
        if let index = alphabet.firstIndex(of: char) {
            pos = alphabet.distance(from: alphabet.startIndex, to: index) + 1
        } else {
            pos = 63
        }
        result += UInt64(pos)
    }
    return result
}

func number2String(_ value: UInt64) -> String {
    var result = ""
    var val = value
    while val > 0 {
        let index = val & charMask
        if index == 0 || index >= 63 {
            result = "?" + result
        } else {
            let charIndex = Int(index) - 1
            result = String(alphabetArray[charIndex]) + result
        }
        val >>= bitsPerChar
    }
    return result
}

for s in [
    "0123456789",
    "abcdefghij",
    "klmnopqrst",
    "uvwxyz",
    "ABCDEFGHIJ",
    "KLMNOPQRST",
    "UVWXYZ",
    "uFxXobTXka",
    "aU57yrm3hF",
    "Grüezi"
] {
    let val = string2number(s)
    print("\(s) = \(val) = \(number2String(val))")
}
```

```
0123456789 = 18590822951584330 = 0123456789
abcdefghij = 201594236381242580 = abcdefghij
klmnopqrst = 384597649810900830 = klmnopqrst
uvwxyz = 33831659748 = uvwxyz
ABCDEFGHIJ = 677403111298354030 = ABCDEFGHIJ
KLMNOPQRST = 860406524728012280 = KLMNOPQRST
UVWXYZ = 62192078718 = UVWXYZ
uFxXobTXka = 570421986625570123 = uFxXobTXka
aU57yrm3hF = 214229433368462506 = aU57yrm3hF
Grüezi = 46657239315 = Gr?ezi
```

Comment: The question clearly shows a string longer than 10 characters. It's probably best to wait until the OP clarifies their requirements before trying to provide a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the code! The code works perfectly! Since it only works for strings with 10 characters, I just broke it up into two 10 character strings(as it is 20 characters long).